# Python's faster alternative to lists for prime numbers?

Tags: python-2.7, list, primes

I need to find the first pair of primes within specified range, these primes must be a certain difference from each other and have no other primes within that difference.
My code seems to be working, but it is painfully slow - I presume because of my use of lists to handle primes. What would be a better approach?

```
g=difference;
n=first number in range
m= second number in range

def gap(g,n,m):

    prime_list = []
    for num in range(n,m+1):
         if all(num%i!=0 for i in range(2,int(num**0.5)+1)):
                prime_list.append(num)

    if len(prime_list)<1:
        return None

    for pnum in prime_list:
        for index in range(len(prime_list)):
            pnum2 = prime_list[index]
            diff = abs(pnum - pnum2)

            if diff == g:

                checker = abs(prime_list.index(pnum2) - prime_list.index(pnum))
                if checker <=1:
                   return [pnum, pnum2]

Some tests:
    Test.assert_equals(gap(2,100,110), [101, 103])
    Test.assert_equals(gap(4,100,110), [103, 107])
    Test.assert_equals(gap(2, 10000000, 11000000), [10000139, 10000141])
```

Comment: Two nested loops over the list of primes makes this horribly inefficient.  Loop once, and check if the next number differs by exactly g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why store the primes in a `list` at all? You only need to remember one at a time.  You'll be working through them in ascending order and, as jasonharper points out, all you need to do is stop when you encounter the first delta equal to `g` between successive primes:

```
def gap(g, n, m):
    previous_prime = None
    for candidate in range(n, m + 1):
        if all(candidate % factor for factor in range(2, int(candidate ** 0.5) + 1)):
            if previous_prime is not None and candidate - previous_prime == g:
                return [previous_prime, candidate]
            previous_prime = candidate
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works beautifully! I guess I was trapped in my "break it down to little steps" too much. Very much appreciated, I've spent hours on this little bit of code for CodeWars.